# Parsing a complex flag in Java

Tags: java, parsing, command-line-interface

I'm working on parsing a particular flag into my CLI in Java. The flag is a "stream" flag, and is denoted by `--stN=`, where `N` represents a number, from 1 to 10000.

The arguments after the `=` are comma-separated, and denote different things - usually a command on how to run a certain operation within the program for the `N`th run through.

These commands can have 0..N arguments themselves.

i.e..
`--st1=command1,arg1,arg2,command2,arg2,3,command3,command4,5`

They can be mix of Strings, numbers etc..

Here's my proposed solution:

Firstly, i've added an interface called `StreamOption` to hold the data that's parsed:

```
public interface StreamOption {
}
```

Next, i've created a `StreamOptionParser` to handle a section of the stream:

```
public interface StreamOptionParser<T extends StreamOption> {
    StreamReturn parse(List<String> stream, int id) throws ParameterException;
}
```

Into implementations of this, i'll hand the stream (as a list, split by comma).

e.g

```
public class CommandOneParser implements StreamOptionParser<CommandOneOption> {

 StreamReturn parse(List<String> stream, int id) throws ParameterException{
  //loop through the list, if terms are found, parse to a StreamObject
  //if not, pass to the return list of strings..
 }
}
```

The result type `StreamReturn` is a simple POJO to allow return of the parsed `StreamOption` as well as any remaining terms that need to be passed to the next parser. I need to return the remaining terms also as a check that all of the inputs are valid, and none remain.

```
//bit of lombok
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StreamReturn<T extends StreamOption> {

    private List<String> remainingOptions;
    private Optional<List<T>> options = Optional.empty();

}
```

It has to hold a `List` as multiple commands can be specified in the same stream.`--stN=command1,2,3,command1,4,5,...`

Is this a good approach? Or is there a better solution that's less boiler platey? Are there any potential issues with this? I think it keeps it extendable, and I can easily add new `Options` and `Parsers` later on, as the program grows.

I couldn't seem to find any libraries/patterns that do this kind of parsing out of the box, are there any I may have missed? I'm using [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) for simple flags, but this seems too complicated for jcommander to handle.

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Comment: I think it is a bit complex for a command line app. Maybe you should use some input file, like a YAML, to describe the commands.

Comment: Would something like [getOpt](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/api/gnu/getopt/Getopt.html) work?

Comment: @viniciusjssouza Interesting idea, i'll look into how that might work - I'm guessing reflection would be involved.

Comment: @WJS Thanks for the suggestion. I haven't used getOpt before, but it looks to me like a simpler, non-annotation based JCommander? Is there a particular part that you think might be good for this?

Comment: This could possibly be handled using `String#split` combined with a rudimentary parser.

Comment: @Sam  Actually I have never used this version. I used to do a lot of `Perl` programming and there as a `getOpt` module from CPAN that was popular.  Unfortunately, I can't tell you much about this version other than it allows processing of commands similar to what most `*nix`  programs use.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using `String#split` to create the `List<String>` and a separate parser for each option.

Comment: @Sam did you looked at any existing command line parsing tools like ANTLR ?

Comment: Perhaps one for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

So, *an* answer was to treat it as a normal CLI argument, by splitting the strings. I then leveraged JCommander to do all of the time-consuming pushing the right command into the right converter.

`command1,2,3,command2,3,string1,command3`

into

`command1`,
`2,3`,
`command2`,
`3,string1`,
`command3`

With this, I leveraged the JCommander annotations to pass the correct args in to the correct command.

```
CommandOneValues{

  int myValue1;
  int myValue2;

}
```

and the option:

```
@Getter
public class CommandOneOptions {


    @Parameter(names = {"command1"},
        converter = CommandOneConverter.class
    )
    CommandOneValues values;
}
```

with a simple converter:

```
class CommandOneConverter implements IStringConverter<CommandOneValues>{

  public CommandOneValues convert(String value){
    //conversion...
  }

}
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Other tools may have features that can give ideas for alternative solutions in addition to a custom type converter.
For example, picocli has some mechanisms for complex options that may be interesting:

- support for [quoted options](https://picocli.info/#_quoted_values)
- [argument groups](https://picocli.info/#_argument_groups) (in beta)

**Quoted Options**

Assuming you defined the option as follows:

```java
@Option(names = "--st", split = ",")
List<String> parts;
```

By default, picocli's `split` function will ignore the [`split` regex](https://picocli.info/#_split_regex) when it occurs inside quotes, so you can use quotes to group arguments. Example user input:

```
--st1="command1,arg1,arg2","command2,arg2,3","command3","command4,5"
```

Picocli will split up the values into these parts:

```
"command1,arg1,arg2"
"command2,arg2,3"
"command3"
"command4,5"
```

The above is the default behaviour for splitting and does not require a custom converter or any other custom code.

**Argument Groups**

Picocli 4.0 will have support for repeating argument groups (still in beta), which may be a different way to model the problem.
Wouldn't it be nice for end users if synopsis of the application looked like this?

```
myapp (--cmd=<commandName> [<commandArg>...])...
```

That is, the `--cmd` option together with zero or more positional parameters become an argument group, and this argument group can be specified one or more times.
The end user would be able to enter values like this:

```
myapp --cmd=command1 arg1 arg2 --cmd=command2 arg2 3 --cmd=command3 --cmd=command4 5
```

The code to accomplish this can look like this:

```java
@Command(name = "myapp", mixinStandardHelpOptions = true)
class MyApp implements Callable<Integer> {

    static class CommandDefinition {
        @Option(names = "--cmd", required = true) String commandName;
        @Parameters(index = "0..*")               List<String> commandArgs;
    }

    @ArgGroup(exclusive = false, multiplicity = "1..*")
    List<CommandDefinition> commands = new ArrayList<>();

    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        // your business logic here
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int exitCode = new CommandLine(new MyApp()).execute(args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```